# Ошибка при вставке данных в базу данных SqLite (Anrdroid Java)

Tags: java, android, база-данных, sqlite

Имеется форма с настройками(информаций о пользователе) и база данных SqLite в трёх файлах(Constants, Helper, Manager)
Для понимания проблемы нужен только метод  ***onCalculateButtonClick***. При нажатии на эту кнопку записываю данные в таблицу, но при следующем считывании их там нет.

В дебагере отображается ошибка, якобы в таблице нет колонки с названием вес.

Ошибка из дебагера:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table user_info has no column named weight
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting gender=empty calories_count= name=test weight=empty growth=empty age=empty current_calories=0
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table user_info has no column named weight (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO user_info(gender,calories_count,name,weight,growth,age,current_calories) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Программный код формы(используется только метод OnCalculateButtonClick)

```
package com.example.fintessassistant;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textViewCaloriesCount;
    private EditText num1;
    private EditText num2;
    private EditText num3;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private RadioButton radioButtonMale;
    private RadioButton radioButtonFemale;

    private User user;
    private DbUserManager dbUserManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        init();
    }



    public void init() // метод инициализации пемременных при создании
    {
        dbUserManager = new DbUserManager(this);

        num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextGrowth);
        num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextWeight);
        num3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAge);
        textViewCaloriesCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCaloriesCount);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupGender);
        radioButtonMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonMale);
        radioButtonFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonFemale);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        dbUserManager.openDb();

        user = dbUserManager.getFromDb();
         num1.setText(user.GROWTH);
         num2.setText(user.WEIGHT);
         num3.setText(user.AGE);
    }

    public void onCalculateButtonClick(View v)
    {

        View view = this.getCurrentFocus(); // скрываем клавиатуру
        if (view != null) {
           InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }



        if(num1.getText().length() == 0 || num2.getText().length() == 0 || num3.getText().length() == 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Заполните все поля!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

            switch (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
                case R.id.radioButtonMale:  // мужской пол
                    textViewCaloriesCount.setText(Double.toString(10 * Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString()) + 6.25 * Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString()) - 5 * Integer.parseInt(num3.getText().toString()) + 5));
                    user.GENDER = "MALE";
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButtonFemale: // женский пол
                    textViewCaloriesCount.setText(Double.toString(10 * Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString()) + 6.25 * Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString()) - 5 * Integer.parseInt(num3.getText().toString()) - 161));
                    user.GENDER = "FEMALE";
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Заполните все поля!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }

              user.NAME = "test";
              user.GROWTH = num1.getText().toString();
              user.WEIGHT = num2.getText().toString();
              user.AGE = num3.getText().toString();

              user.CURRENT_CALORIES = "0";
              user.CALORIES_COUNT = textViewCaloriesCount.getText().toString();

              dbUserManager.clearDb();
              dbUserManager.insertToDb(user);
         }



    public void openMainActivity(View V) // открытие формы с питанием
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        dbUserManager.closeDb();
    }
}
```

Константы для базы данных:

```
package com.example.fintessassistant;

public class DbUserConstants {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "user_info";
    public static final String _ID = "_id";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String GROWTH = "growth";
    public static final String WEIGHT = "weight";
    public static final String AGE = "age";
    public static final String GENDER = "gender";
    public static final String CALORIES_COUNT = "calories_count";
    public static final String CURRENT_CALORIES = "current_calories";



    public static final String DB_NAME = "user_db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_STRUCTURE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            NAME + " TEXT," + GROWTH + " TEXT," + WEIGHT + " TEXT," + AGE + " TEXT," + GENDER + " TEXT," +
            CALORIES_COUNT + " TEXT," + CURRENT_CALORIES + " TEXT)";

    public static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
}
```

Хелпер для базы данных

```
package com.example.fintessassistant;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DbUserHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbUserHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DbUserConstants.DB_NAME, null, DbUserConstants.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DbUserConstants.TABLE_STRUCTURE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DbUserConstants.DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

}
```

Менеджер для базы данных

```
package com.example.fintessassistant;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DbUserManager {

    private Context context;
    private DbUserHelper dbUserHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DbUserManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        dbUserHelper = new DbUserHelper(context);
    }

    public void openDb(){
        db = dbUserHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void insertToDb(String name, String growth, String weight, String age, String gender, String calories_count, String current_calories) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DbUserConstants.NAME, name);
        cv.put(DbUserConstants.GROWTH, growth);
        cv.put(DbUserConstants.WEIGHT, weight);
        cv.put(DbUserConstants.AGE, age);
        cv.put(DbUserConstants.GENDER, gender);
        cv.put(DbUserConstants.CALORIES_COUNT, calories_count);
        cv.put(DbUserConstants.CURRENT_CALORIES, current_calories);

        db.insert(DbUserConstants.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }

    public void insertToDb(User user) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(DbUserConstants.NAME, user.NAME);
        cv.put(DbUserConstants.GROWTH, user.GROWTH);
        cv.put(DbUserConstants.WEIGHT, user.WEIGHT);
        cv.put(DbUserConstants.AGE, user.AGE);
        cv.put(DbUserConstants.GENDER, user.GENDER);
        cv.put(DbUserConstants.CALORIES_COUNT, user.CALORIES_COUNT);
        cv.put(DbUserConstants.CURRENT_CALORIES, user.CURRENT_CALORIES);

        db.insert(DbUserConstants.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }


    public User getFromDb() {

        Cursor cursor = db.query(DbUserConstants.TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,
                null,null,null);

       if(!cursor.moveToFirst()) return new User();

        @SuppressLint("Range") User tmpUser = new User(
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbUserConstants.NAME)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbUserConstants.GROWTH)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbUserConstants.WEIGHT)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbUserConstants.AGE)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbUserConstants.GENDER)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbUserConstants.CALORIES_COUNT)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbUserConstants.CURRENT_CALORIES))
        );

        cursor.close();

        return tmpUser;
    }

    public void clearDb() {
        db.delete(DbUserConstants.TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    }

    public void closeDb(){
        dbUserHelper.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В методе `public void onCalculateButtonClick(View v)` попробуй удалить строку `dbUserManager.clearDb();`

Если я правильно понял, ты сначала удаляешь базу данных, а потом пытаешься вставить в нее запись

Comment: Да, действительно, помогло. По задумке, эта строка должна была очищать строки в бд, а не удалять её. Большое спасибо)